# Como definir o tamanho de uma página com RaveReport

Tags: delphi, pdf, relatório, delphi-2010

Tenho um projecto em Delphi 2010 no qual utilizo o RaveReport para a realização de relatórios em PDF, a minha questão e a seguinte e possível definir o tamanho `Width` `Heigth` da página PDF.

Eu tentei isso mas dá erro:

```
var PWidth: Double;

PWidth := 20;
System.BaseReport.PageWidth := PWidth;
```

Comment: Qual erro está acontecendo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solução para o meu problema:

```
procedure TfrmLogger.RvSystemBeforePrint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Sender as TBaseReport do
    begin
      Units := unInch;
      UnitsFactor := 1;
      SetPaperSize(DMPAPER_USER, 21, 29.7);
      Units := unCM;
      UnitsFactor := 2.54;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Marque então sua resposta como aceita

Comment: Ok. aguarde então.